# Is it possible to pass Windows HLK test for drivers compiled with WDK7.1

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

We are facing critical situation about signing our drivers.
I am wondering, is it possible to pass windows HLK test successfully for the drivers which are compiled with WDK 7.1

Because we were able to sign them using HCK but now after some bug fixes, the new version has to pass HLK test for windows 10 support, which can't !

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Yes.**

The **best** thing you can do is just compile your drivers using **wdk10** using **VS2015** keep target OS as **windows7** install it on **windows10** and test it using **HLK.**

Or secondly you know that drivers are forward compatible if they are compiled for windows 7 they will work on **windows 8.1 or windows 10** as well.

You just install your **wdk7.1** compiled drivers on windows 10 OS. Then setup the client server for **HLK** and put the test for windows 10.
After that whichever tests fails just read the errors and solve them.

Some modifications will be there if you want to give support for windows 10 OS **Ex:** **NonPagedPool** should be replaced with **NonPagedPoolNx** etc.

But yes you need to change the code according to errors you are getting on test fails and fix them on your own there is no easy way.

Yup there will be lot of work but that is possible for sure, I have done that for **PCI serial port drivers**.