# Develop driver to support Windows 7 through 10

Tags: driver, wdk

I am developing a kernel mode driver to support my custom PCIe device. I am using WDK 10 with the target platform set to Windows 7. Is there any reason that this driver won't support everything 7-10? Are there any precautions I should take (apart from not using API calls that are deprecated in 10 or not supported in 7; I assume the target platform setting would produce warnings/errror if I made this mistake anyway)?

According to windows docs, a pre-W10 driver must be signed using HCK, while a W10 must be signed with HLK. If I want to support 7-10, do I need to sign the same driver with both (can a driver be signed twice?) or just one of the two? Or am I better off with a third party signing service? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754453/is-it-possible-to-pass-windows-hlk-test-for-drivers-compiled-with-wdk7-1):

> The best thing you can do is just compile your drivers using wdk10 using VS2015 keep target OS as windows7 install it on windows10 and test it using HLK.

Will a driver tested/signed with HLK install without error on Windows 7?

Just for context, I already have a proof of concept device and kernel driver working on my windows 10 test machine. I am rewriting the driver to be production quality and robust in OS support. Thanks for any input!

Comment: `Will a driver tested/signed with HLK install without error on Windows 7?` As long as Test Mode is enabled on the environment (or you disable driver signature enforcement for each session) then the driver will work fine given it is compiled as architecture like the OS one (e.g. 32-bit driver for 32-bit Windows, 64-bit driver for 64-bit Windows) and is built to support the OS you're running (e.g. Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, or all. etc.).

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR Thanks for the reply. The intent is to build a driver to distribute to end users. I don't want the user to need any special settings enabled on their machine such as test mode or disabling signature enforcement. I am asking for the proper way to sign a driver so that it will install on W7-W10 without disabling signature enforcement. Will signing with HLK meet this requirement?

Comment: Sorry I think I misread what I was quoting the other day. Basically if the device driver is signed with an authentic certificate which supports kernel-mode signing then it'll work on all OS other than Windows 10. On Windows 10, very early on, the requirement is an Extended Validation certificate, and then it'll be fine. However, for Secure Boot systems, you'll need the Microsoft co-sign which would be through the Windows Hardware Portal thingy.

Comment: The Test Mode/Driver Signature Enforcement disable on the session thing is only if you have a test certificate for the driver instead of an authentic one which was issued.